# Removing repeated words or characters with input from user

Tags: java

I am trying to remove duplicates from an input. There are numerous ways to do this, using ArrayList, LinkedList , Hash set etc. I know how to do this, if the input is given as say{"apple", "ball", "apple", "cat"}, specified in the problem.
But I want to use to scanner class and get input say a line and want to remove duplicates in the character, or remove duplicate words. Do you have a simple way to do this.
I have included my working code for the earlier scenario.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here

        Scanner scan= new Scanner(System.in);
        String[] str= {"a", "b", "c", "a"};
        System.out.println("enter text");
        List<String> l= 
                Arrays.asList(str);
        System.out.println(l);
        Set<String> set= new HashSet<String>(l);
        System.out.println(set);
    }
```

Comment: There *should* be a simple way.. examine avb java data-structures

Comment: what does "avb" mean? -novice

Comment: - available .  ya i knoooooow

Answer (score 1):

The following will read each word and add it to the hashset (which removes dups automatically which you figured out) and will stop when a word is ! and print out the set..

```
    Scanner scan= new Scanner(System.in);
    HashSet<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
    String s;
    while (!(s = scan.next()).equals("!")) {
        set.add(s);
    }
    System.out.println(set);
```

Comment: Some how I am not able to get this to print the set. I have even tried "scan.hasNext()". Also used for-each loop. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: hasNext() can be blocking - i.e. it will wait until it has input and then return true - so you won't leave the loop. You will need to break the loop somehow, for example when you type in a word that breaks it.